# Can I force floats to only appear in the left column of a `twocolumn` article layout?

Tags: floats, two-column, adjustwidth

I work for a journal that employs a two-column layout.
To the left of the two-columns is some extra empty space which figures, tables, and textboxes can take up to stand out a bit more, see below for some examples.
The figures are wrapped in an `adjustwidth` environment to pop them out to the left, e.g.:
[image]

The problem I’m running up against is (predictably) that sometimes LaTeX thinks the figures should go in the right column, which leads to unflattering scenarios such as this:
[image]

I want LaTeX to *always* place figures in the left column, is there any way to do this?

Things I’ve tried/considered:

1. Just moving the figure around until it moves to the left column. This sort of works but a) can take quite a lot of time when there’s a lot of figures, and is quite fragile to small changes in the text and b) I’d ideally like to use the TeX file to generate an HTML version as well, so ideally the figure would be in a place in the text that makes sense (e.g. at the end of a section).
2. `\FloatBarrier` is not super helpful.
3. `\newpage`-ing to manually break the column also is not fantastic.
4. Just using bare `\includefigure` and `\tabular`, so no floats. This usually breaks up the text in a less than flattering way, I would like the figures to float, just not in the right col.
5. The package `multicol`: AFAIK this package does just not allow for floats at all.

See this MWE: Is there anyway to have Figure B be around `\section{More Figures}` in the code but appear in the left column? (Does not really matter to me on which page the figure appears, as long as it’s close-ish)

```latex
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[left=20em]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{adjustwidth}{-15em}{}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \end{adjustwidth}
\end{figure}

\kant[1]

\section{Introduction}

\kant[2-4]

\begin{figure}
  \begin{adjustwidth}{-15em}{}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
  \end{adjustwidth}
\end{figure}

\section{More Figure}

\kant


\end{document}
```

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This modifies part of `\output` to check `\if@firstcolumn`.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[left=20em]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\let\@leftfloatplacement=\@floatplacement
\def\@rightfloatplacement{\global\@topnum=0
  % Textpage bit, global:
  \global\@toproom=\z@
  \global\@botnum=0
  \global\@botroom=\z@
  \global\@colnum=0
  % Floatpage bit, local:
  \@fpmin=\@colht}
\def\@floatplacement{\if@firstcolumn\@leftfloatplacement
  \else\@rightfloatplacement
  \fi}
\makeatother
  

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{adjustwidth}{-15em}{}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \end{adjustwidth}
\end{figure}

\kant[1]

\section{Introduction}

\kant[2-4]

\begin{figure}
  \begin{adjustwidth}{-15em}{}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
  \end{adjustwidth}
\end{figure}

\section{More Figure}

\kant

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just a note: `\z@` could also be used for the numbers not only the lengths.

Comment: Very late reaction, but thank you so much! That works quite well, although it does have the issue @barbara beeton describes, but it's good enough for me!

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @JohnKormylo is good, but it might end up putting a figure on page *n*+1 when the reference is in column 1 of page *n*.  It all depends on where in the source file the input for the figure appears.

Input for a figure must always appear in the source file when there is still space available to place it in the intended location in the output.  So if the reference for a figure is halfway down the first column and the figure input isn't included until after the reference, it will be held over to the next page.  All floats referenced in the second column, if input is "delayed", will be held for a later page, even if there would have been enough space on the same page.

The suggested approach is manual. and best delayed until the text is final, but it gives you full control.  Place the input for a figure *before* the text that will begin the page on which the figure is to appear.  Float input is best included in vertical mode, with a blank line above and below it.  It may make sense to place each float in a separate file, at least temporarily, so they can be moved around easily.  The detailed code can always be moved into the main source file after placement in the output is fixed.

Comment: unless top floats are prevented, a figure with source towards the end of column1 can be floated backwards and placed at the top of that column.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- True.  I didn't state that correctly.  Thanks.

Comment: It might be possible to implement a package simitlar to multicol (which formats the entire page as one column) but where the floats must total less than `\textheight` and the floats and text fogether must total `2\textheight`.